# Change a Spring MVC redirect from a GET to a POST?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm doing a redirect from a Spring MVC controller by returning a String containing the URL:

```
return "redirect:/my/form/newpage.html?pid=".concat(myform.getId().toString());
```

this gives a string like this:

```
redirect:/my/form/newpage.html?pid=456
```

The trouble is, the Spring `ModelFactory` class appends all our session attributes to the query string and it looks horrible.   I'd really like to change this redirect from a GET to a POST, but I have no idea how to do that.   Can anyone help?

Comment: You cannot. A redirect is implemented as a GET at the HTTP level.

Comment: Why all your session attributes becomes appended to query string? Are you using RedirectAttributes for this? if you want send POST take a look on springTemplate/HttpClient. If you make redirect to the same app you can use session to pass this data.

Comment: Perhaps you want flash attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really change the HTTP Method of redirect but

you can try this to avoid exposing  variables to path (instead these explicitly added like pid):

```
public ModelAndView redirectToSomewhere() {
    RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView("/my/form/newpage.html?pid=".concat(myform.getId().toString());
    redirectView.setExposeModelAttributes(false); // these
    redirectView.setExposePathVariables(false); //two depend on the way you set your variables
    return new ModelAndView(redirectView);
}
```